# Numerical integration: efficiency and precision

Tags: numerical-integration

I have an array of values $f[x,y]$ which was calculated numerically for "grid" ${x,y}$ and I have steps ${dx,dy}$.

I would like to know how can I perform numerical integration,
$$\sum_{i,j}dx_idx_jf(x_i,y_j)$$
with high precision. I use simply

```
Sum[dx[[i]]*dy[[j]]*f[x[[i]],y[[j]]],{i,Lenth[x]},{j,Length[y]}
```

I assume that there is a function in Mathematica which does it with higher precision. Or, can anyone suggest where can I found Mathematica realizations of methods of numerical integration (like Simpson's rule, etc.)

Comment: I recently did such an operation with an array `{x,y,z}`, where x and y represented points on an irregular mesh, and z - the values in these points. I did it as follows. First, used the 1st order interpolation to get an interpolation function. Second, I integrated it using `NIntegrate` routine, and, by trial and error, selected a suitable numeric strategy. Hope this helps.

Comment: `array.dy.dx` is a speedier equivalent to your `Sum`, assuming `array` is the array of values $f[x_i,y_j]$. Your `Sum` code suggests you have access to `f`, so you could use `NIntegrate` on it. With `NIntegrate`, you would probably get a more satisfactory result. If you have access only to the data, then interpolating as @Alexei suggests is a good idea. Most likely one could avoid `NIntegrate` and directly apply the rule associated with interpolation, or use FEM to do it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 unfortunately I have extremely small values of `f[x,y]`. Thank you for advice with `array.dy.dx`. Can I simply use my array as the argument of `NIntegrate`?

Comment: No, the argument to `NIntegrate` has to be a function.

Comment: @MichaelE2 firstly I misunderstand your point about `f`. I have not `f` explicitly.

Comment: If you need help with integrating `f`, ask a question.  You would probably have to include the definition of `f` to get help, though.  Problems are usually specific to the function.