# Multidimensional NIntegrate with Interpolating

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I have a numerically evaluated function `f[x,y]` (it is impossible to write down analytical epxression for the function `f`) and array of points `{x,y}` with constant steps in `x` and `y` directions. I try to perform suggested strategy (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/numerical-integration-efficiency-and-precision)) My data is not pretty and `Interpolation` says me that `InterpolationOrder` should be set to `All` or to `1`. If I use `->1`, it returns

```
Interpolation::fememtlq: The quality -1.21606*10^-15 of the underlying mesh is too low. 
The quality needs to be larger than 0.`.
```

Then, I obtain interpolation function and try to perform `NIntegrate`. However, when I try to do this, it seems that Mathematica kernel crashes.

To be honest, I know nothing about numerical integration but I think that `Method` specification in `NIntegrate` can help. I can provide my data and result of "naive" calculation (just replace integrate by sum over points).

I try to understand which method of `NIntegrate` should be used. I plot `DensityPlot` of interpolating function and (may be) it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simpler test function for the sake of illustration. Let's take the following function over the implied rectangle, which can integrated exactly for the sake of comparison with the approximations:

```
f = Function[{x, y}, Exp[2 x - y]];

N@Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}]
(*  25.4648  *)
```

One approach, depending on whether the fixed-step rectangle grid is itself important, is to use an `ElementMesh`:

```
Needs@"NDSolve`FEM`";
emesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0., 0.}, {2., 3.}]]
(*  ElementMesh[{{0., 2.}, {0., 3.}}, {QuadElement["<" 425 ">"]}]  *)

fIFN = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, f @@@ emesh["Coordinates"]];

NIntegrate[fIFN[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh, 
 Method -> "FiniteElement"]
(*  25.4647  *)
```

To increase accuracy, use a finer mesh:

```
emesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0., 0.}, {2., 3.}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> "Length" -> 0.01]
(*  ElementMesh[{{0., 2.}, {0., 3.}}, {QuadElement["<" 60000 ">"]}]  *)

fIFN = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, f @@@ emesh["Coordinates"]];

NIntegrate[fIFN[x, y], {x, y} ∈ emesh, 
 Method -> "FiniteElement"]
(*  25.4648  *)
```

Another approach is to use a regular interpolation and `Integrate`:

```
fIFN = FunctionInterpolation[Exp[2 x - y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}];

Integrate[fIFN[x, y], x, y] /. {x -> 2, y -> 3}
(*  25.4618  *)
```

To improve the result, use more interpolation points:

```
fIFN = FunctionInterpolation[Exp[2 x - y], {x, 0., 2.}, {y, 0., 3.}, 
   InterpolationPoints -> 101];

Integrate[fIFN[x, y], x, y] /. {x -> 2, y -> 3}
(*  25.4648  *)
```

`Integrate[InterpolatingFunction[...][x,y], x, y]` returns $\int_a^x\int_b^y f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$, where the domain of the interpolating function is of the form $a \le x \le c$, $b \le y \le d$.

Comment: If I specify rectangle `Rectangle[{-1.04065, -1.04155}, {0.001, -0.148707}]`, `ElementMeshInterpolation` gives error about interpolation on unstructured grids. How can it happen? I assume that rectangle is structured grid..

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov I get no such error with this: ``Needs@"NDSolve`FEM`";
emesh = ToElementMesh[
   Rectangle[{-1.04065, -1.04155}, {0.001, -0.148707}]];
fIFN = ElementMeshInterpolation[{emesh}, f @@@ emesh["Coordinates"]];
NIntegrate[fIFN[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] emesh, 
 Method -> "FiniteElement"]``.  Did you use `Interpolation` instead of `ElementMeshInterpolation`?

Comment: Can this error occurs due to nature of my function `f` or should this approach work for any function?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov I don't think `ElementMeshInterpolation` gives such an error.  `Interpolation` does give such an error.  It doesn't have anything to do with the function `f`. If you can't share the code you used, then I'm guessing at what you're doing and I may be wrong.

Comment: Sorryy! I have made the silliest mistake. Everything works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your data is in the following form
`data = {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...,{xn,yn,zn}}`
Then you can create your interpolating function, where the interpolation will be linear. Something to be careful of is that if your grid spacings, e.g. x1 - x2, are not uniform across your whole grid, then you may run into trouble. Moreover, if your grid isn't square, you'll have problems. Make a square grid, and any region you don't want to integrate just set it to zero. With this in mind, define your interpolating function
`fn = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder->1]`
and integrate
`answer = NIntegrate[ fn[x,y],{x,x1,xn},{y,y1,yn},Method->"QuasiMonteCarlo"]`
I like the method QuasiMonteCarlo, since monte carlo tends to be fast, and the quasi random sequence of points generated in the quasimontecarlo routine is more uniform than the points chosen from the PRNG in the MonteCarlo method, so you're less subject to sqrt(N) noise in your answer.

Comment: It seems that argument of `Interpolation` should be given in form `{ {x,y}, f }`  ,not `{x, y, f}`