# Two-dimensional numerical integration with multi-valued function

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

How can I compute two dimensional integral for the function `f[x,y]`, which is multi-valued?

This function appears as follows:

1. For a given pair `{x,y}` I solve numerically with `NSolve` the equation `g[x,y,z]==0` with respect to `z`.
2. Then I compute `f=F[z]`, where `F` can be (for instance) `Sqrt` function. So, I deal with function `f` which depends on `(x,y)`

Naively, I evaluate this integral using integral sum:

1. Creatre grid `{x,y}` with spaces `dx` & `dy`
2. Then compute `f=f[x,y]` at every point `{x_i,y_i}`
3. Sum all contributions `f[x_i,y_i]` at a given point `{x_i,y_i}`
4. Then sum over grid with weight `dx*dy`

This procudure has convergence issues due to complicated structure of `f`: the function depends on parameter `a` and for differrent values of parameter my computation produce outliers (for instance, the typical value of integral is about `0.5` and for some values of `a` the integral value blows up to `32000`). Handling with the function `f`, it seems that integral saturates in a very small domain in `(x,y)`-space. In addition, the described computation scheme works slow.

About one year ago I have asked the related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224895/multidimensional-nintegrate-with-interpolating) and have obtained very detailed answer from MichaelE2. At first glance, it seems good idea. However, when I have implemented the suggested solution the convergence problems appeared: the mentioned function depended on a parameter `a` and there were outliers in integral values for different values of parameter `a`.

Comment: I would compute the values on a grid (as you do).  If the function varies relatively slowly, there might be some advantages in using a neighouring value to start the `NSolve` search (would `FindRoot` be a better choice?).  Doing a 3D plot of the values could give you an idea of where unreliable values lie.  It might be worth do 2D interpolation on these values and then integrating that.  Might a log transformation make your function better behaved?  (Log before fitting surface, the Exp afterwards)

Comment: @mikado thank you for ideas! Currently I use `NSolve`, `FindRoot` seems irrelevant because I am interested in roots in the given range, i.e. `z1<z<z2` where `z1` & `z2` are known constants